# How to Integrate Google Assistant SDK (Library component) with Android device

Tags: android, python, adb, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to embed Google Assistant in an Android device I'm prototyping (Snapdragon 820 Development Kit, Android 8.0). I'd like to use the Google Assistant Library because it allows for hands-free activation. However, it runs on Python and I am unsure how to get that running on my device.

Has anyone successfully integrated Google Assistant Library with a prototype Android device, or a device without Python running on it? Please advise.

If I need to install Python on Android, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid trying to install Python onto Android. You could look at [existing projects](https://github.com/kuri65536/python-for-android/blob/master/README.md) but there is not official support or a strong guarantee that it will work at all.

For the moment, it would be better to either prototype your system using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian if you really want to use [the library](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/). Alternatively, use the [service API](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/) on Android.